# dll to main program communication

Tags: c++, dll, callback, ipc, printf

I want to trace some text from dll module to a main program window (to a log subwindow). How can I do this correctly? (through kernel primitives, via sending messages from window to window, passing callback interfaces?) The working example I've seen: Matlab and Octave. When calling `mexPrintf` then output printed in their main windows.

Comment: What function does the DLL use for generating output?  For example, C++ iostreams allow redirection by replacing the `streambuf` with `std::cout.rdbuf(some_buffer_which_sends_to_window);`

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'm using the QT framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main program should export a logging function and make it known to the DLL.  Your DLL needs to export a function, such as InitLogging, that takes a function pointer and stores the passed value somewhere into its global data.

An alternative is to put your "main" program in another DLL and make a "stub" main that links all the DLLs together.

(On Windows, DLLs can call each other's functions, but a DLL cannot call a function in the main program. On unix, this is much simpler, as shared objects can directly call the main program's functions.)

Comment: +1 for the correct windows answer *and* the vastly simpler Unix one!

Comment: Thank you! But how can I call external function from dll on linux? When I'm creating `-shared` library on linux `gcc` says me about undefined symbols.

Comment: Use dlopen() with NULL as filename; that will return the handle for the main program. You can then use this handle with dlsym to get hold of any functions in the main program having external linkage. Though it is strange that you get an error, the ld manual says that --allow-shlib-undefined is default.

Comment: I've just made a simple test program with shared library calling a function in main, and everything linked and executed fine.

Comment: Yes, I've check it under linux - all as you say. But on Mac OS X - it all as I've described. So different ways :(