# Getting symbols for explicitly loaded DLL from the application

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am modifying my application so that it can explicitly load a DLL (through the Windows API) and call some functions from the DLL. But I need to be able to call some application's functions from the DLL too. I can only provide header files of the functions to the DLL. But I am getting the LNK2019 'unresolved external symbol' error.

Is my idea even feasible?

Comment: Can you clarify, please? Does your exe need any *implicit* loading of the DLL (i.e., does it need to be link-time dependent)? If not, then you can actually use the exe 'like' a DLL and have it export the relevant functions to the DLL (which would import them from the EXE). I think.

Comment: Thanks for reply @AdrianMole! I am not sure if I understood the idea behind your comment but I'll try to answer. I am explicitly loading the DLL because I want to be able to load other DLLs and I want to choose the DLL before running the application. So no, my application doesn't need to load any DLL implicitly. Yes, I know that I can 'switch the roles' of the application and the DLL but I just want to know if my idea would be possible.

Comment: OK, if your DLL compiles with the relevant headers (for the functions defined by the EXE), then those functions need to be `dll(export)` in the EXE build and `dll(import)` in the DLL build. To resolve the linker error(s), you will need to add the EXE's 'export library' to the inputs for the DLL build. I've only ever used this for MFC Extension DLLs, and the loading/resolution for those is a bit different, so can't be 100% certain this is feasible. (Apologies if I'm preaching to the choir, here!)

Comment: An alternative would be to have function pointers and dummy 'stub' functions in your DLL, then have the EXE send its real function addresses to the DLL after a successful LoadLibrary call (but that would be tiresome if you have many such functions).

Comment: @AdrianMole what do you mean by "add the EXE's 'export library' to the inputs for the DLL build"? I am using MS Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: For a DLL project, VS will automatically generate an import library (calling it import or export is a bit semantic - depends on your POV). For an EXE project, you have to **explicitly** tell the linker to do so: Project->Properties->Linker->Advanced and specify a location/name for the import library. Your DLL will need to be linked against this (in its additional input libraries, or using a `#pragma comment(...` somewhere in the code).

Comment: It works! Thank you @AdrianMole for your fast response. I'll write some thread answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Adrian Mole 

, I have .exe projects that export symbols and haven't needed to name the .lib file in the project settings (I checked one such project before making this comment), it is produced as normal for any binary that uses __declspec(dllexport). I haven't tried with projects that use either .def or command line exports but would not expect those to be any different.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Thanks for clarifying that. Almost all the projects I have on-hand actually have EXEs that export, but I select the locations manually - so I couldn't remember what leaving that property empty did wrt an import lib.

Comment: @PeterVeris For the goal in your initial question: *my application ...explicitly load a DLL ...and call some functions from the DLL. And...call some application's functions from the DLL too.* For first part, you can refer to [Exporting from a DLL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=vs-2019). For second part, you can pass function (which is defined in your application) pointer into the DLL and let DLL can call it. Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404628/how-to-call-a-function-defined-in-my-exe-inside-my-dll) for more detailed info.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks for additional help but I find Adrian Mole's solution easier for me at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @AdrianMole for solving my problem! To resolve the external symbols in the DLL you'll need to create an import library of the EXE. In Visual Studio 2017, this can be done by going to the project properties. Go to Linker → Advanced and set the Import Library setting to the path and name you want. (For example: `$(TargetDir)\myimportlibrary.implib`). Then, go to the the DLL project properties → Linker → Input and add the import library to the Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: This doesn't address the question that was asked. As stated, you want to import exports from an **explicitly** loaded DLL (i.e. a module that was loaded using `LoadLibrary ` and friends). It's unclear why you presumably get link-timer errors while implementing a system that's strictly verified at runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, I am not a C++ professional but since the executable and the DLL were different projects I assume that the DLL didn't have the symbols it needed when compiling.

Comment: @IInspectable I think the problem was that the *DLL* depends **implicitly** (at link time) on functions exported by the *EXE*. The EXE's dependencies weren't the problem. I have this sort of arrangement with plug-in modules: the EXE uses `LoadLibrary` to load them, so no need for it to use an import library. However, the plug-in (DLL) uses functions (classes, actually) from the EXE, so needs to be linked against that EXE's import (export) library.

Comment: @adr The DLL could use [run-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking) to get to the services exported by the EXE. Although interfaces provide a far more resilient and maintainable solution to the problem of cyclic dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

So you found a way to do this, however you should also ask yourself whether you *should* do it.

If your executable depends on the DLL then the DLL should not depend on that executable. This is not just a question about principles but also about avoiding future problems.

The way you could achieve the calls from the DLL to the executable is to define a function-pointer type and a setter in the DLL's headers:

```
typedef void aCallbackType(void);
void setMyCallback(aCallbackType* Cb);
```

In `setMyCallback` the DLL stores that function-pointer to later call it.

Then the executable can define a function and give that to the DLL:

```
void myCallback(void) { }
void myProgram(void) {
    setMyCallback(myCallback);
}
```

Comment: It is my understanding, I may be wrong, that "the DLL calls into the EXE via exports made by the EXE" is the way nodejs dynamicaly loaded native modules using "N-API" are built. I would think it's simple, robust and efficient.

Comment: Actually, I use this paradigm to implement optional plug-in modules for an exe (see comments in the other answer). The plugin-in is designed to work **only** with that specific EXE, and can safely have link-time (implicit) dependence on the EXE (and require its generated import library). However, the EXE loads the DLL optionally (and explicitly), so no link-time dependencies.