# How to call functions defined by caller of a dll from dll's source in C/C++?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll

I want to call functions defined by caller of a dll from dll. I am working on a C/C++ application. Main application may or may not use certain dlls as per the configuration provided and both the sides(Main application and dll) need to invoke each others functions. These example explained fairly well how one can create a dll and call it's functions at runtime.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2019

However it doesn't explain how can I call functions defined in Main application from dll.

When I try to declare the same function in dll's headers it throws error saying failed to find function.

How can I tell to linker that certain function will be available at run time. In gcc there is --export-dynamic. This can be used for exporting the symbols and later shared object is able to use these symbols. Is there something similar in windows?

Edit:

Following discussion gives a possible solution, Here caller must pass the function to dll as argument.

[How to call a function defined in my exe inside my DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404628/how-to-call-a-function-defined-in-my-exe-inside-my-dll)

This will be little cumbersome to use in my situation. I am trying to port here a linux application on windows. There are many methods which are called by dll. Passing all of them to dll as function doesn't sound as a good idea however this can be doable as last resort. Other downside I see on taking this approach is, this will require Main application to be changed on every time plug in(dll) wish to use some new function of Main application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function defined in my exe inside my DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404628/how-to-call-a-function-defined-in-my-exe-inside-my-dll) or [dll to main program communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221776/dll-to-main-program-communication)

Comment: Thanks @jdigital. That is a great help. However I will appreciate if there is way to achieve it without passing function pointers.

Comment: in what problem export functions from exe ?

Comment: take a look at the other possible duplicate article, which suggests _...put your "main" program in another DLL and make a "stub" main that links all the DLLs together_.  The role of a DLL is to provide externally accessible methods.

Comment: @jdigital - for what all this ?! *role of a DLL is to provide externally accessible methods* ? why not from exe provide externally accessible methods ?